# How to add a new column to an existing table with websql

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I have an android  app (created with cordova) that is already live and in use. There are some data being stored on the device database. I have to make an update that requires an additional column to one of the tables in the database. I want to add the new column without the need to clear the app storage so i created a function that attempts to add a new column before executing some other function dependant on that table. here is the code for that altering code

```
var alterEntryTable = function()
{
    qObj = $q.defer();

    dbService.db.transaction(function(tx) {

        tx.executeSql(
            'ALTER TABLE entry ADD created_at TIMESTAMP ',
            [],
            function (tx, rss) {
                qObj.resolve({error: false});
            }, function (tx, rss) {
                qObj.resolve({ error: true});
            }
        );
    });

    return qObj.promise;
};
```

the problem is that it always returns an error. someone help please. Thank you

Comment: Please post your error message.

Comment: it just gives an sqlError object. i dont know how to access the details inside the object for display on the console.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in your error handler is a SQLError object. You can log its message property to get details on the error.

```
function (tx, rss) {
    console.log(rss.message);
    qObj.resolve({ error: true});
}
```

Did the error message help at all? I think you're missing `COLUMN` in your SQL. It should be `ALTER TABLE entry ADD COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP`.

Also `timestamp` is not a [datatype in SQLite](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html), but it's harmless to keep it there.

Comment: Even when i use other data types i get the same problem

Comment: What does the error say? I've added details on how to log it